# ParseException when changing data type in Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

In my `Databricks` notebook, I am getting `ParseException` in the last line of the code below when converting string to Date data type. The column in `csv` file does correctly have `hiring_date` in a date format.

**Question**: What I may be doing wrong here and how can we fix the error?

**Remark**: I am using `python` and NOT scala. I do not know scala.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.csv(".../Test/MyFile.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")
df2 = df.withColumn("hiring_date",df["hiring_date"].cast('DateType'))
```

Comment: Which error message are you getting?  Can you share it with us?

Comment: @PhuriChal Only thing it displays in output window is just `ParseException` with a plus sign to expand the error message. But when I expand it the only details it shows in the line where error occurred (that is the last line of the code in my post above. That actually prompted me to post this question here. I am using [Azure Apache Connector for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the last line of your code, with reference to this [doc](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-cast-column-type/), the code should be modified as follows:

```python
df2 = df.withColumn("hiring_date", df.hiring_date.cast(DateType()))
```

It seems you put a wrong value for cast function.

The following code would work as well:

```python
df2 = df.withColumn("hiring_date", df["hiring_date"].cast('Date'))
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked (thank you). You are correct, I was using wrong syntax. It should be `DateType()` instead of `DateType`. Also thank you for providing a link to an online documentation, it helped, as well. My upvote.